# Angular, Run function on interval, timeout

Tags: php, angularjs

I have written the following controller that gets info from my DB and displays in in my app:

Controller:

```
.controller('activityCtrl', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
    $http.get("user.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
})
```

user.php

```
<?php
//DB stuff goes here
$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"Regid":"'  . $rs["Regid"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"Fname":"'   . $rs["fname"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"Lname":"'   . $rs["lname"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"activity":"'   . $rs["activity"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"ID":"'. $rs["id"]     . '"}'; 
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();
//echo($outp);
?>
```

Now Im trying to modify the controller so it runs getData function and updates the view at a predefined interval and Im having some trouble incorporating the necessary portions for the update with what I already have working. here is the controller as it has been modified:

```
.controller('activityCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$scope.getData = function(){
$http.get("user.php")
.success(function(data,status,headers,config){
//The next line needs to be modified to work with the new code
//.then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
console.log("data fetched");
        });
    };
$scope.intervalFunction = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.getData();
        $scope.intervalFunction();
    }, 1000)
};
$scope.intervalFunction(); 
});
```

Currently I have the console.log running for testing and everything is functional. I have my older line of code commented out; this is the line I need to rewrite in order to display the data as needed. Any help is very much appreciated.

The interval is working already; I dont know how to rewrite the .success function so it displays the results from the $http.

Comment: Don't try to create json manually ... it is very time consuming and error prone and can be done simply using `json_encode($array)`

Comment: Is `success` firing? Do you see the `data fetched` message? Really not clear what specific problem is

Comment: Yes, the console.log is reporting as needed.

Comment: So what is the specific problem?

Comment: @charlietfl -  If I comment .success and uncomment .then the whole script stops working. I need to rewire .success so it displays the data like .then does

Comment: Should work..what errors are thrown?

Comment: @charlietfl - if I comment .success and uncomment .then I get the following error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:

Comment: likely a syntax error then when you are changing. Right now you show it inside the success so if you leave the close braces of success syntax won't be right. the version at very top of question should work

Comment: I fixed the issue by using $scope and setInterval instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry your question is pretty unclear to me, as in what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to run your code repeatedly after a certain time frame then you can just use the $interval service. Can you be more clear on what you are trying to achieve and where is the problem?

Comment: Ive edited the post- I need to update my one line of code so it works with the rest on the new code

Answer (score 0):

Use `$interval` instead of `$timeout`

```
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.getData();
    }, 1000);
```

See More : [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Comment: The interval is working already; I dont know how to rewrite the .success function so it displays the results from the $http.

Comment: I think the same success function should work. If you want to append the new results to the old one, use  `<Array>.push()` and a `ng-repeat` in the markup.

Comment: Its not working, which is why Ive posted the question. If I comment .success and uncomment .then the whole script stops working

Comment: It should be `then` instead of `success`

Comment: that doesnt fix the problem

Comment: Maybe you should try creating a fiddle for us to understand the real problem

Answer (score 0):

While technically not an answer what are you doing in *user.php*?
I think you're trying to create a JSON string but I question your methods.

```
<?php
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row; // or just use a fetch_all?
  }

  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what Im doing

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using $scope and setInterval instead. Here is the new controller in case anyone needs a reference:

```
.controller('activityCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.value = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
   $http.get("user.php")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
    }, 1000);
});
```